# Changing a normal android app to vr app using Unity 5.4 and gvr sdk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I made a simple android app that have a main menu with 5 buttons and when you press a button a box will appear beside the menu depending on which button you pressed.

I made the menu and boxes as a UI( buttons, panels and scrolls).

I want to make it working with VR or Google cardboard and instead of pressing a button just gaze on it, and I want it as a 2d. The menu is fixed and not moving as user move the VR, and only the pointer (gvrReticle) is moving to click a button.

I downloaded "gvr unity sdk" and try to make my app using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do few things:

1. Import Google VR SDK
2. Run sample scene to know how things are placed
   (specifically UI).
3. Change the canvas from screenspace to world space
   etc

Follow this tutorial further: https://www.raywenderlich.com/116805/make-vr-game-unity-google-cardboard